# What are your naming conventions for SQL Server objects?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are seemingly a lot of very diversive naming convention recommendations for sql server objects. I was wondering if there are some formal guidelines other than not prefixing stored procedures with sp_ ?

---

As pointed out by Matt, there is already a similar question: [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions) , so please vote for closing this one (I don't understand why I can't close my own question?!?).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 2):

i use usp for sprocs, udf for functions, vw for views and trig for triggers.
i don't use anything for tables.

this isn't necessary and some don't reccomend it but this way i keep the grouping of the same objects if i'm querying sysobjects or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I normally just use a prefix using the first three letters of the table I'm working in for all items (i.e. empID).

Answer (score 0):

Although it's probably not necessary, I prefix some object types:

```
tr_  for triggers
fn_  for user defined functions
```

There are not a lot of the above and the prefix makes them easier to find in the source.

For tables and stored procedures, and most views, I use a prefix that indicates the business area of the object.  For example in my current project

```
dal_  for CRUD select, insert, delete
ac_  accounting functions
rep_ for reports
se_   security
```

...

and so on.  Makes it easier to find a stored procedure or to know the purpose of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Well I used to use tblTableName, vwViewName, spStoredProcedure fldFieldName. Now after having worked with Databases for some time, I find the tbl, vw, and fld unnecessary extra characters to type.

I do stick with the spStoredProcedure though, not sure why but it's pretty easy to type spSomething.

For tables, I now name them with something descriptive and the same for fields. I generally use lowercase for the first word and then uppercase on the first letter of the second word.

ie: employeeRecords, spGetEmployees, etc.