# Naming conventions for DB triggers

Tags: database, triggers

Are there any naming conventions for DB triggers?

For example "before delete on users" would be "bdUsers" or something like that.

Comment: One probable duplicate or related question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For sorting reasons I would recommend a structured approach:

```
TR_Users_AD
TR_Users_BD
TR_OtherTable_AI
```

and so on.

In the end it's up to you - but whatever you choose to do, stay consistent, at least within the same database.

Comment: and keys should be consistent.

Comment: Why don't your example names indicate the type of operation: insert, update, delete?

Comment: @rory They do. "AD" = "After Delete", "BD" = "Before Delete", and so on.

Comment: Why do you insert `TR` for triggers? You do not name table `STUDENT` as  `TB_STUDENT`.

Answer (score 25):

I agree with @tomalak - but i normally spell out the action at the end instead of abbreviating it...

```
trig_Users_delete
trig_Users_insert
trig_OtherTable_Insert
trig_OtherTable_InsteadOfInsert
```

Comment: While consistency is key and keys should be consistent, clarity should not be overlooked.