# Style guide for database metadata naming

Tags: database-design

We want to establish some database metadata naming rules in our new project. For example:

- tables are named as nouns in a plural
  form (**courses, books, lessons**)
- if present, an adjective goes before
  a noun in a table name and is separated
  by an underscore (**red_books,
  new_lessons**)
- table index column is always named
  **id**
- foreign key names are derived from a
  table name with suffix _id (**books_id,
  red_books_id**)
- so on

Does someone know any guide like this?

Comment: is this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions ?

Comment: It is not. My question is more generic - I am interested in a naming guide for all SQL database metadata objects - tables, indexes, foreign keys, views, materialized views, triggers, functions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that sounds reasonable, so do what works for you.  **Having a formal standard is the way to go, whatever it is.**  What works for you and your database is not necessarily what will work for someone else.  For example, if I have 8,000+ tables, then I will have a different way to name them, possibly prefix them with a module/area, etc.  should you follow that standard?

Comment: Mmm. It is not a problem to create a guide, but I want to reuse some existing. This is not because I lazy, but because I want to make some economy. In my experience, a reuse of existing product is far less expensive than creation from start.

Answer (score 2):

There are good links and discussion in this question:

[Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)

You can probably take your pick of the styles there.

Answer (score 0):

There's some documentation to be found on SQL naming conventions. [Here's one, for example](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-naming-convention-should-i-use-in-my-database.html)

Also never use a dot '.' in any SQL server object name as this will break a number of tools, including Microsoft's own SqlBulkCopy class.

Comment: I see you are .NET guy. Microsoft a big company with many standards. May be you can remember some public guide from Microsoft on this topic?

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Using the waybackmachine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150417002132/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-naming-convention-should-i-use-in-my-database.html