# Database tables naming, plural or singular

Tags: database, visual-studio

When naming tables and schema of the db is it best to use singular or plural.
For example. should it be Customers or Customer?

And when naming should it be Capital such as Customer or customer? Any best practice regarding naming?

Comment: Also similar to: [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)

Comment: Duplicated by [Table Naming Dilemma: Singular vs. Plural Names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/338156/90527), but that one got more attention.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question calls for a religious war.

I have no doubt it should be plural because...

- A table is a collection of rows.
- The SQL syntax becomes more natural - `SELECT * FROM Customers` instead of `SELECT * FROM Customer`.
- The analogy to OOP - you have a class `Customer` and a list or other collection of customers called `Customers`.
- `SELECT * FROM Customers AS Customer WHERE Customer.FirstName = 'John'` - `Customers` refers to the whole table while `Customer` refers to the current row.

**Negative things**

One has to switch several times between singular and  plural during the development. You may start with a conceptual model - for example an entity relationship model - where the natural choice is to name the entity `Customer`. From this model you generate a database and must pluralize the name to get the `Customers` table. Finally you pick your favourit O/R mapper and it has to singularize the name again to get a class named `Customer`.

If you have to do this manually because the tool is lacking support (for example EntityFramework prior to .NET 4.0) it might be a reasonable choice to keep the table names singular but therfore get a class `Customer` instead of `Customers` without changing it by hand.

Comment: +1 for your first paragraph, even though your opinion is wrong :)

Comment: I used singular naming but after switching to rails where plural is the standard the plural naming feels more natural. This is especially true for queries

Comment: It seems more natural but I was thinking if it has any negative effects later on in development etc...

Answer (score 8):

singular naming.

it's all about the tuples, not the tables, and a tuple is one customer, not customers. also i prefer naming in lower cases, but thats for no reason, i just learned it like that in school.

in the end, as others said, it's more a matter of preference. more important than the choice if to use plural or singular is to stay consistend and do it the same way for all tables - if you mix pluar and singular naming, it's a real mess.

Comment: "It's all about the tuples" Exactly: "tuple**s**". It is about ALL the tuples and not about a single tuple. A label for a table is also not a label for a single tuple, but a label for all tuples. A SELECT statement always selects ALL rows and then you can reduce the number of rows with WHERE or JOIN afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty much a matter of preference

Answer (score 5):

Do you select a `recipe.ingredient` or a `recipes.ingredient`?

...or do you select an `ingredient` from `recipes` instead of an `ingredient` from `recipe`.

Do you select a `recipe.ingredient` list, or a `recipes.ingredient` list?

...or do you select an `ingredient` list from `recipes` instead of an `ingredient` list from `recipe`?

I think consistency is more important that the convention itself.  Personally, I prefer singular, lower case table names, but I'm not going to vehemently defend that choice.

Comment: You do not select `ingredient` from a single `recipe`. You ALWAYS select `ingredient` from ALL recipes and only afterwards if you want you can reduce the number of results with `WHERE` or `JOIN`. So it is `recipes.ingredient` as in "choose the ingredients field of all recipes" and it is "select `ingredient` from `recipes`". It is plural all the way.

Answer (score 0):

My choice are Singular and TitleCase :)

Customer is an entity. Table is the logical collection of multiple entity. So plural is preferred.

For table names pascal case is better. i.e., CustomerMaster.

It is preferred to use prefix such as tblCustomerMaster.

If you are using group name as prefix then use it in capital letters like,
NEWCustomer, OLDCustomer