# Best practice for naming SQL table columns

Tags: sql

I will get involved in a big project and I would like to know which is, in your opinion, the best practice for naming SQL table columns.

Lets say we have a products table. Which of the following naming will you prefer?

- id,
- name,
- description,
- photo,
- price

or

- product_id,
- product_name,
- product_description,
- product_photo,
- product_price

Comment: @RedFilter, I don't understand you question.

Comment: Questions like this that are a matter of taste or preference have no real "correct" answer and should therefor be marked with the "Community wiki" flag.

Comment: Psyche:  It's practice on here to mark questions community wiki if you're asking questions where people answer with their opinions.  Questions and answers that are CW can get badges (most of the time) but no reputation.  Some people have gotten really spun up about other users getting a lot of reputation for "opinion" type questions.  I personally don't care, because my SO reputation and 64 cents will buy me a cup of coffee.  But I'm not everyone.

Comment: This is not a matter of taste, Hes is discussing the relevance of an old and unthinked pattern. This is important.

Comment: The second one really bothers me. In the project I am currently working on, the convention was to use TABLE_NAME and Table_Name_Column_Name, because this "avoids ambiguity", etc. But then foreign key columns get named the same as the referenced column, so you start seeing things like `WHERE FIRST_TABLE.Second_Table_ID = SECOND_TABLE.Second_Table_ID`. And most of the table names are longer than that too. Ugh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 28):

Prefixing column names with the table name does not add any benefit and clutters up code.  The first choice is better.  Only column "ID" may have benefit with the prefix as this is likely a key, and there are likely other tables with that same column.

Comment: Say you have a table with two id columns - how do you know which is which?

Comment: +1 for `table_id`: its great as it doesn't cause any problems with name clashes when you're using multiple tables at once, but there usually isn't much use elsewhere.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I think that's why Russ says that it is okay to prefix the ID column with the table name.

Comment: @alan, that's why you can qualify a column name with the table name in a query, to disambiguate the columns.

Comment: @Russ: Your "no benefit and clutters up code" is informational - anything to not have to check the table definition to know what a column represents

Comment: For surrogate primary key columns (which is what "IDs" usually are), I'd include the table name, e.g. ProductId (skip the underscore, save on keyboard wear and tear). That way, if (say) table ProductPart had columns ProductPartID and ProductId, you'd know right off the table's primary key (since it has that table's name on it), and you'd know what table ProductId references.

Comment: Agreed. A significant benefit of using the table name in identity columns is that you can see that your joins are correct by inspection, e.g. if I write `p.ProductId = pp.ProductPartId` then it's clearly wrong, whereas `p.ProductId = pp.ProductId` is clearly right.

Answer (score 11):

Definitely the first one. Second is a violation of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: Agreed, usually table will have a name explaining what the entries in it are.  In this case products.

Answer (score 6):

I'd think in most cases the first would be fine, since you generally need to specify the table in your queries.  So if the name of the table (or alias) is descriptive, then things like `product.id` would be clearer than `product.product_id`.

Answer (score 4):

The first option is my choice simply because one already knows what table the fields are from. In addition, I'll use <table name>_<key field> in other tables as a foreign key field name (`product_id`, for example).

Answer (score 4):

Tables

```
Product
ProductCategory - prefix with underlying table name, could be other categegories
```

Columns

```
ProductID,      - prefix with a table name
CategoryID,     - note that it's not a ProductCategoryID
Name,
Description,
Photo,
Price
```

Keys

```
PK_Product_ProductID  - primary key
AK_Product_Name       - alternative key (unique column)
FK_Product_CategoryID - foreign key
```

Indexes

```
IX_Product_Price
```

Comment: Let me know if you need names for other assets in your database. I am one of the best in a naming convention field :)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the first choice, don't repeat the table name in the field, what happen if the table change name?

if you are going to use a lot of table with same field name, it doesn't matter, use aliases

Answer (score 3):

If I have a products table and a customers table my id becomes ProductID and CustomerID respectively.  I find it simplier since ID could mean anything especially if you are trying to return both in a query.  But it is all a matter of preference.

## But keep it consistant is all I can say.

Comment: +1: For consistency and informational column naming conventions.

Comment: +1: For the large font and bold at the end!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with those who say that the table name should be omitted from all the columns except for the ID.

If a column is a foreign key, then I like to give it the same name as the column it references. This tends to keep things simpler and easier to remember. There are two exceptions to this rule. If more than one foreign key references the same column in the same table, then they will need some kind of prefix based on their use to distinguish them. And if a foreign key has a specialized use then it may need another name (ManagerPersonId rather than PersonId for example).

This rule about foreign key names encourages prefixing the ID column with the table name.

Also, if a table's primary key is a synthetic identifier, like an identity column, then it becomes very natural to name it TableNameId, since that describes exactly what it is.

In all other cases, prefixing column names with the table name is needless, redundant, and verbose.

Answer (score 2):

No one has mentioned this so I thought I would - I struggle with things like the "name" column.  I find myself prefixing generic columns like "name" because it's so ambiguous.  But I do that for readability, not as a blanket prefixing rule.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find the product_ prefix redundant and irritating. This is, however, ultimately, a matter of personal preference (or team consensus).

Answer (score 1):

The first one, without a question. Naming the id column Product_id might be useful in some cases (though I can't think of any at the moment), but otherwise there's absolutely no point in repeating the name of the table in the name of each column.
And in case you choose the other alternative, I've grown to dislike _ in column names, so I'd use ProductId instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would only prefix the ID (PK) column with the table name as you can have consistent names for columns when using it as a FK in another table. No need to prefix the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the second.  It's not a matter of Don't Repeat Yourself (it's not code).  Product fields are only useful with products, and nothing else.

See ISO/IEC 11179 for more ideas why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add the table name only for the ID eg. `product_ID` merely due to personal preference and leave the rest as they are on your first example.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is very important.

While defining the own table ID you should use only ID, however when defining a foreign key field you should use the table name.

A table with a name Table1 and the filds:

- Table1Id
- Table1Name

This doesn't make sense, right?

However On foreign keys the foreign key field should have its table name prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of the prefix is when you want to join tables
For example, if you have two tables:

- products

  - id
  - name
  - category_id
- categories

  - id
  - name

To be able to get each product with the matching category you must use `select * from products join categories on category_id=categories.name` because both tables contain "name" field.

But, if the fields will be with prefix:

- products

  - product_id
  - product_name
  - product_category_id
- categories

  - category_id
  - category_name

You will able to do just `select * from products join categories on category_id = category_name`

The problem with the second way is that the field names are too long.
To solve the problem, i saw another way:

- products

  - p_id
  - p_name
  - p_category_id
- categories

  - c_id
  - c_name

With this way you receive the benefit of both ways together.
Both short fields and simple joins.