# Database relationship when one entity is optional

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am making a school management system. The basics are as follows:

There will be a School table such as:

```
id  
school_name
```

A school will have several branches. So there is Branch table in which I have school_id as foreign key such as:

```
id  
branch_name  
school_id
```

A branch will have several Students (I am skipping Classes and Sections and other stuff to make it simple) so there is a Students table as below:

```
id
student_name
branch_id
```

This case is simple where a school must have a branch. I want to know what if a branch is not mandatory? If there is no branch then how will you design the Students table then?
Will it have another field for "school_id" in addition to "branch_id" like this?

```
id  
student_name  
branch_id  
school_id
```

So if there is no branch then "branch_id" will be 0 while "school_id" will contain value from parent School table? Is this the correct way?

Comment: I personally cringe if i see fieldnames like `school_name`, `branch_name` and `student_name` because it is just repeating information. Inside the scope `school` it is just the `name`.

Comment: Actually it's a good practice to use it that way so by just looking at the field you can tell to which table it belongs.

Comment: The only possible advantage i see is when doing joins, but it still does not tip the scale. For me it is totally against anything object oriented. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524731/best-practice-for-naming-sql-table-columns

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. The situation you describe isn't a straightforward fit for most relational databases. You have a bunch of options.

I would suggest introducing a default branch for each school, and associating the student with that branch. This kinda breaks your logical model - you suggest that in the business domain, some schools have no branches. Not sure how you define "school" and "branch", but if this situation is about "virtual" branches for internet learning, you could create a branch called "internet". 
For simplicity, this is the easiest way to go - if you want to know which students belong to a school, you always run the same query; if you want to know which school a student belongs to, you always run the same query.

If the business domain really does require this distinction, I'd suggest a table called

```
> StudentAssociation
> - studentID
> - schoolID
> - branchID
```

This allows you to factor out the relationships between students and institutions, and you can create database triggers to allow only one association (a student belongs either to a branch, or to a school, but not to both).

By factoring StudentAssociation into a separate table, you can also track history - add columns reflecting the dates, and you can track a student's movement between branches or schools.

Comment: I already got answer to this question and i.e. use "parent_id" field in School table. There is no need to have a separate Branch table. If a school doesn't have any branch then its "parent_id" will be 0. If it is a branch then it will contain "parent_id" of its school.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table like this:

StudentBranch (student_id, branch_id)

student_id would be the key.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could say that a student always belongs to a school, and secondly to a branch.

So yes, i would indeed propose a student-table as you said:

```
id
name
school_id (NOT NULL)
branch_id (could be NULL)
```

A student will only be part of 1 school and possibly 1 branch, so i see no need to extract into a different link-table.

In the case you want to maintain a history, I'd rather introduce a table keeping the history of previous schools/branches, but keep the current school/branch immediately retrievable inside the student-table.

I am not sure what data you would keep at school, and which at branch level. Just to make sure you can treat each student in the same way, you could define a view that handles that for you. E.g. something like

```
create view student_v
  as select student.name, branch.name, ... from student, branch if student.branch_id not null
  union select student.name, school.name, ... from student, school if student.branch_id is null
```

[pseudo sql, but you get the drift i hope]