# MySQL table and field names should be uppercase?

Tags: mysql

Or they should be lowercase letters? Is there any standard for it?

Comment: Personally we prefer lowercase, separated by underscores. So, for instance we'd have a table called my_table_name. The cool thing about this is that our ORM managers translates this in code to myTableName when it creates a PHP class for it, but that's just a preference. There's not really a standard with it. I guess a "standard" would be "whatever your other tables are using as their naming convention".

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions as well as this http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/tablefieldnaming.htm and finally this one http://www.gplivna.eu/papers/naming_conventions.htm

Comment: I don't know if there are MySQL-specific conventions, but I personally like to stick to the Clean Code approach that names should be devoid of "encodings" and should carry meaning and context.  If someone looks at a name in a domain and thinks "Oh, they must be using MySQL" then that sounds like a leaked abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

i always use lowercase for mysql table and field names. You can use (_) underscores in tablenames and fields to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both upper and lower cases both twogether and individually. Till now I did't get any issues. For more than one word I use underscores to separate them. Also you can use like this for example sampleTable.