# would my database naming be any trouble?

Tags: database, database-design

today i start a project and design my database,here's my design doc's content.

```
user    
id          int
name        string

account 
id          int
gold        int
silver      int

accountdetails  
id          int
content     *

role
id          int
name        string
sex         char
portrait    string
figure      string
level       int
exp         int
speed       int
actionpoint int
skillid     int

roleskill   
roleid      int
id          int

roleskillD  
id          int
effect      string
name        string
image       string
level       int
```

i use the laziest way to naming the fields and tables. i think it wouldn't cause me trouble.

i found i have no trouble to read name like these:

```
accountdetails
actionpoint
skillid
roleskill
```

etc.i don't like to use casing or _ in database.

give me your instruction if you feel things don't go right.

Comment: While different case can cause problems in some database software, there is absolutely no problem with using underscores.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions?

Comment: Separating words can be useful - is it "role skill" or "roles kill"?

Answer (score 1):

A database is usually a *shared* resource.  You should design it so it's easy for everybody to use.

Bear in mind that your identifiers may get longer and that some flavours of database (such as Oracle) will store the object names in upper-case.  `CUSTOMERCONTACTADDRESSID` is harder to read than `CUSTOMER_CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID`.