# An OleDbParameter with ParameterName "" is not contained by this OleDbParameterCollection

Tags: c#, ado.net

I keep getting a parameter name error? at the bottom I have attached an image to help explain the problem.

```
private void loadProgress(string jobNumber)
    {

        productioninfo.Open();

        OleDbCommand _contractReview = new OleDbCommand ("SELECT [Contract Review] FROM [Main$] WHERE [Job No] = '@Job No'", productioninfo);
        _contractReview.Parameters.Add("@Job No", OleDbType.Char);
        _contractReview.Parameters["Job No"].Value = jobNumber;

        OleDbDataReader dr = _contractReview.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {

        }
        dr.Close();

    }
```

[image: ![image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/54t7xcfhkj7sghu/Parameter%20name.jpg)]

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
OleDbCommand _contractReview = new OleDbCommand ("SELECT [Contract Review] FROM [Main$] WHERE [Job No] = @JobNo", productioninfo);
_contractReview.Parameters.Add("@JobNo", OleDbType.Char);
_contractReview.Parameters["JobNo"].Value = jobNumber;
```

And don't use spaces in your table and column names. It is not recommended.

Check out [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)

Comment: Would the same apply to excel sheets? thats where I am getting my information from

Comment: @user2315803 I'm not sure about the excel part but you could try this without any spaces.

Comment: @JobNo parameter or ? parameter ?