# Codeigniter Update dynamic Database name error

Tags: php, codeigniter, escaping, sql-update

I have some problems when I update my table with Ci Update. 
Here is my Code

```
$db = $this->input->post('db');        
$tbl = $this->input->post('tbl');       
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$col = $this->input->post('col_name');    
$id =  $this->input->post('id');   
$array = array($col => $name);   
$this->db->where('id',$id);  
$this->db->update("`$db`.`$tbl`", $array);
```

Problem is database name. Database name can possible include "." sign. eg( db3.9 )
So Ci is produce update query like this

```
UPDATE `db3`.`9`.`mytbl` SET `name` = 'myname' WHERE `id` = 1
```

So anyone can tell me how can i solve this CI update auto escape solution.
PS. removing database name from this query is not what i want.
because database,table and columns are dynamic.So i can't define globally what database,table and columns.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps use ci's query function instead to avoid auto escaping

```
$db = $this->input->post('db');        
$tbl = $this->input->post('tbl');       
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$col = $this->input->post('col_name');    
$id =  $this->input->post('id');
$this->db->query("UPDATE `$db`.`$tbl` SET `$col` = '$name' WHERE `id` = '$id';");
```

i havent seen many examples of people using dots in their database names (even though it is technically allowed), but ive commonly seen underscores being used.

this might help [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)

Comment: that's the right answer. Also, you could set 'protect_identifiers' to false in the DB config file, but that's global. As a hack, you can also set $db->_protect_identifiers to false.

Comment: yes . . . but it can't solve my problem. because my database name and columns is dynamic. I mean I don't know what database need to update and what columns are need to update.So i can't write query like this.

Comment: @SeanPyae it should still work, since your executing a single update with each post request, ill update the answer to match your revised question

Answer (score 0):

use the escape character in defining the dbname??? LIKE `$db = "db3/.9"`