# Can Someone explain meaning of this exception? Connection String, Table Name, query syntax are correct

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, sql-insert

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_AStatus (Asset Status,Remarks) VALUES (@a, @b)", Login.sqlConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtAssetStatus.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", txtRemarks.Text);
int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
```

Exception shown:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 32,Token in error = Status ]

Comment: bad idea to have space in column name `[Asset Status]` if you really have it.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table name or column names includes white space, you need to use them with square brackets like `[Asset Status]`. But this is not recommended. Would be better changing your column name to something else if you can.

Read: [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects.

```
using(SqlCeCommand cmd = Login.sqlConn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_AStatus ([Asset Status],Remarks) VALUES (@a, @b)";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAssetStatus.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRemarks.Text;
   // I assume your column types are NVarChar
   Login.sqlConn.Open();
   int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
}
```

And don't use `AddWithValue` method. It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes. Use [`SqlParameterCollection.Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) and it's overloads.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thank you Soner for help. Now it is showing result of ExecuteNonQuery() as 1 but no change in database

Comment: @Shreyas Are you sure? If `ExecuteNonQuery` returns `1`, it **has** to insert to your database. Did you try this query in your database manager? It successfully inserts in there?

Comment: @Shreyas _Well_, do you use local database file for this? Try to connect it on Visual Studio's Sql Server Object explorer menu and try this query on your local file.

Comment: thank you so much. It is working fine now, it was because of slow machine. Thank you so much. It was much needed. Suggestions Welocme!!