# Query more slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I do a query but does not show anything on the screen and when I opened the page where I do the query is slow and does not show anything

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Dettagli_macchina WHERE  macchine_id='$macchine' and Email='$_SESSION[login_user]'";
$result = mysqli_query($conne,$query);
                    while($row=mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                        echo $row['COMPONENTE'];

                    }
```

Comment: While with mysqli_num_rows???? U will use mysqli_fetch_array here. mysqli_num_rows will return no of rows not rowData

Comment: Its slow because loop is infinite always true

Comment: Now u have lot of solutions try it.

Comment: When you say DOES NOT WORK.. please please please explain what you mean. The code should work perfectly, so either you have no matching records or something is wrong with your SQL query, which we can't tell because we know nothing about your database.

Answer (score 4):

[`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) will only use for getting no of rows not for row data.

You need yo use `mysqli_fetch_*()`

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo $row['COMPONENTE']; 
}
```

Why this query slow? Because you are using infinite loop here, always *TRUE*.

```
while($row=mysqli_num_rows($result))
```

One more story, I hope you are using `session_start()` in your file, but suppose that if `$_SESSION` not found or not start than your query will failed.

*In last, this is just a suggestion regarding **Naming Convention**, you are using column name in small letter, capital small, full capital, this is not related to answer but you must need to learn about this art.*

---

*this will help you to understand Naming Convention: [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)*

*This reference will help you to  understand how `mysqli_fetch_array()` works: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php*

Comment: I use a session and i include session_start

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching record but using mysqli_num_rows() which return total number of rows/records replace it with mysqli_fetch_array() here is the working example.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Dettagli_macchina WHERE  macchine_id='$macchine' and Email='$_SESSION[login_user]'";
$result = mysqli_query($conne,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //replace mysqli_num_rows with mysqli_fetch_array 
      echo $row['COMPONENTE'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this one for return value and if you need number of raw then the statements will be different.

```
  $query="SELECT * FROM Dettagli_macchina WHERE  macchine_id='$macchine' and Email='$_SESSION[login_user]'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conne,$query);
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo $row['COMPONENTE'];

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you have mixed up the mysqli_num_rows function, here I am using it to print the number of results found, then loop through the results after converting the mysqli result object to an array named $row

```
    echo 'Found '. mysqli_num_rows($result) .' results';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo $row['COMPONENTE'];
   }
```

Comment: `does not work` actually tells me very little. Do you mean it showed an error? or it just found ZERO results?