# DB naming convention for main column (name vs entity)

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

I have a table (stations) containing TV station names that are then used via FK in other tables. I was wondering if there is a convention or preferred way to name its columns.

Option A:
id, name

Option B:
id, station

Pro A:
It is very descriptive in the full context (stations.name)

Pro B: 
makes it more descriptive when used without the table prefix (station vs name).

Comment: "name" is a lousy name.

Comment: @jarlh but it is the logical property name. Consider each row as an object. A station object could have more properties (stations: [ {id: 1, name: "ABC", viewers: 123456, owner: "Corp LLC."} ]) I can't see why name is not a proper choice for the information it contains

Comment: check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions

Comment: @Chris "Consider each row as an object" is a bad idea. Rather consider each row as a proposition. Objects are represented by PK and FK values. A row represents a fact about one or more objects.

Comment: @reaanb Ok, I agree, but the argument about the naming is the same regardless of considering it an object or part of one/many object/s

Comment: @Chris Option C: **station_id, station_name**. I don't recommend mindlessly prefixing all fields with the table name, rather the point is to distinguish unique domains (since station ids and names aren't interchangeable with e.g. channel ids and names). I would not add channel_ in front of a station_id FK in a channel table. However, I would add an additional prefix when the role of a column needs to be clarified, e.g. if a table has multiple columns of the same domain.

Comment: Another, more controversial approach is **station, station_name**. This reinforces what I said about objects being represented by PK and FK values, but it seems most people prefer to use _id as a suffix for surrogate keys.