# Naming decisions for database tables

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

**Database table:** Some people say that the database table name should be "plural" and some debate for "singular". Is there any standard for renaming the database tables?

**Database table columns:** Some argue that database column should start with table name as a prefix and some say that it is repeating the same thing twice.

Can anyone help me with what's right and why?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: This question looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions